# Magento 2 - How to add custom response header to every page?

Tags: magento2

I am new to Magento 2 and found no information how to add a simple response header to every page like

```
header("header name: value")
```

So how and where must a response header be set in Magento to every page?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it within your .htaccess file, adding the line:

```
Header add Header-Name "header value"
```

This way you don't need to change Magento code

Comment: No, It must be a PHP header. Header added in .htaccess doesn't work for my case.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: The different is what the header is used for. In my case and usage it is used for Litespeed Cache.

Comment: Not sure, but I think adding it to index.php should work. Otherwise you will need to extend the response class